# Any experience with Karvonite NoSQL document database / persistence store for .NET?

Tags: .net, nosql, object-persistence

Has anyone used [Karvonite](http://www.karvonite.com/) as a persistence store for .NET desktop applications?  I see they just came out with a new version 5 in November, 2012.

Looks very promising:

- mapping of data model looks trivial
- very lightweight deployment
- very good integration with .NET ecosystem

Seems like it might be a lightweight alternative to RavenDB embedded.

I'm thinking it may be the NoSQL equivalent of SQLite.

But there's very little info on the web, which worries me.

What was your experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the Karvonite 4 release in a production application and I couldn't be happier with it. I had a need to store a small amount of application configuration data along with a roughly 10 to 100 data records in some form of persistent storage.

I debated between using SQL Compact Edition and Karvonite. SQL Compact was nice and worked well but seemed to be more difficult to deal with in terms of upgrading and rolling back the database. In my opinion, it also created tighter coupling between my application code and the persistent storage mechanism.

Karvonite on the other hand allowed me to almost completely separate my application code from the backend storage mechanism. I was able to quickly and easily define the database as well as migration paths for upgrades and downgrades. I am looking forward to upgrading to Karvonite 5 when I get some free time to take advantage of some of the new features.

Comment: I belatedly accepted your answer...have not been on SO for a while. Can you persist more complicated object graphs with it, such as collections or dictionaries of other complex objects?

Comment: @TomBushell - Yes, below is the list of built in objects supported by the Karvonite 5 framework: Boolean, Byte, Decimal, Int16, Int32, Int64, SByte, Single, Double, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64 Char, String, Guid, DateTime, TimeSpan, Enumerations (including flag enumerations), System.Collections.IList, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(T), System.Collections.IDictionary, and System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary(TKey, TValue)